# I want to use Push Notification for My app for IPhone

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I want to use Push Notification service for my app ,but I am not sure how to utilize this ,please help

Comment: We have to know if you mean local notifications (sent from the user iphone itself) or remote notifications (sent from a server)?

Comment: I have to use local notification b/c client is not providing any third party server plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a good tutorial for push notifications here explaining the server side implementation details:
http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/
and here explaining the client side details:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Also here is the link to the Apple developer guide on local and remote push notifications: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To send remote push notifications using PHP, I suggest you take a look at the `php-apns` project on Google Code. I've had good experience with it.

You will have to enable push notifications on iTunes Connect, if you didn't do that already. Your app will have to get the push notifications token from the OS, and deliver it to server. This token may change from one launch to another, so recommended way is to fetch the notification token at launch, and deliver it to the server. Server can then decide when it wants to deliver a notification to which device; at that point, you use `php-apns` which will connect to Apple's server on port 2195 (make sure you have a hosting which allows that) and, using several certificates you also put on the server, communicate with it.

Make sure the certificates are not downloadable when you upload them on the server.

You cannot test push notifications on the Simulator.